# How to execute maven goal but ignore potential local pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven

I have a script that shall use maven to download an artifact to the local maven repository:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:get -Dartifact=org.jasypt:jasypt:1.9.3
```

However, when the script is executed from a directory that contains a `pom.xml` then maven also parses this POM and prints the reactor, etc. causing confusion. Even worse when the `pom.xml` is invalid for whatever reason the command fails.
What I want is to ignore any local pom.xml. Is there a way to do this with a maven CLI option or something similar?

I already studied the [CLI options](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-embedder/cli.html) but could not find any option for this. I tried with something like `-f /tmp` but it seems that `-f` option does the oposite of what I want as it requires a POM file or a directory containing a `pom.xml` or the build will immediately fail.
Any other ideas instead of creating an empty directory in my script, CDing to it, invoking maven and then CD back and delete the empty directory?

Comment: Why using the command instead of simply adding this dependency to the pom and maven will download it automatically without supplementally calling command line and why using scripts for such things which are done by Maven by default?

Comment: @khmarbaise this could be done for reasons beyond the scope of the current maven module, e.g. to download and install a (rpm,deb-)package that needs to be available for the maven build, which happens to be available in a maven repository

Comment: Creating an RPM can done as welll no need to make manually a dependency:get ...

Answer (score 1):

My work-around is to have a minimal POM reflecting an artifact created by the Maven invocation that needs to ignore the actual POM,

```sh
groupId=".."
artId=".."
ver=".."
echo "<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${artId}</artifactId>
    <version>${ver}</version>
</project>" > target/min-pom.xml
mvn -f target/min-pom.xml PLUGIN_GOAL_CREATING_GROUP_ARTIFACT_VER
```

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#minimal-pom